# IMAP getting UID List of selected folder

Tags: imap

How can I retrieve the list of IMAP UIDs from the selected folder?  I want to get the list of mail UIDs, so I am passing the `1150 UID FETCH FLAGS (\Seen \Flagged)`, but I am not able to retrieve the list: it gives me an error like `BAD Command`.  So how I can retrieve the list of UID from the selected folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest (and most compact) way to list all the UIDs in the currently-selected folder is via `UID SEARCH ALL`:

```
A001 UID SEARCH ALL
* SEARCH 288 291 292 293 295 323 324 325 326 327 385 387 472 474 641 720 748
A001 OK UID SEARCH completed
```

The errors in your `UID FETCH` request were leaving out the sequence-set and including a list of flags.  If you rewrote it as

```
A002 UID FETCH 1:* (UID)
```

or

```
A002 UID FETCH 1:* (UID FLAGS)
```

it would work.

Comment: UID SEARCH result not getting flags can you please help me to get the flag result in Search